How to efficiently distribute governance rewards?
I want to give a token reward for every governance member who voted to a Snapshot proposal. I know that Snapshot offers a feature called Boost, which will become a paid feature after its beta phase. My question is, how can I efficiently distribute rewards to governance members after a successful Snapshot voting period? Are there any examples or best practices for doing this, especially considering the potential gas fees associated with rewarding every voter?
PS: If it would be an on-chain governance, I could put 100 tokens to a contract and create a record every time a user votes (then user would need to withdraw but I wouldn't have to pay for every user). But now I want to use Snapshot which is an off-chain governance.
PS2: I know I can make a batch transfer/record.
